# How to load jingle_peerconnection_so.so file to an android project in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webrtc

I get the following error while running the project. I don't know how to add jingle_peerconnection_so.so file to an android project in eclipse?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jingle_peerconnection_so from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nandha.quickblox.videocall-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.nandha.quickblox.videocall-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Comment: Hey did u find the solution?

Comment: I m facing the same issue need help plz

Comment: create "armeabi-v7a" folder inside lib folder and  place the .so file inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

use System.load("location of .so file");  or
System.loadLibrary("location of .so file");

Comment: I use this solution but not solve my issue please refer other solution because my app is crash in Tab7".

Answer (score 0):

It's a JNI file thats missing. 
Add the file libjingle_peerconnection_so.so to your jniLib folder inside src/main

This file should be in the output directory of the webrtc folder